# Creating a new subscription in Braintree reqires 3D Secure check. How to get the paymentMethodNonce?

Tags: braintree, braintree-sandbox, braintree-javascript

I have a problem with creating subscriptions in Braintree. I use hosted fields, not DropIn ui.
Creating a subscription flow is the following:

1. User registers a card (Visa, MasterCard and so on)
2. I create a user and a payment method in the same back-end function. 3D Secure auth in front-end works perfect, I get the paymentMethodNonce and I use it for creating a client and payment method.
3. HERE I HAVE A PROBLEM. User must choose a subscription, after clicking a button UPGRADE, I run a back-end function to create a subscription. Before it worked well, and it still works well for MasterCard, but for Visa card it returns an error:  processorResponseCode: '2099'. As I understand I need to run 3D Secure check one more time for creating a subscription. But I cannot use nonce which I used for creating payment method, then I get an error "Cannot use a payment_method_nonce more than once".

MY QUESTION, If I need a new PAYMENT METHOD NONCE, how can I get it? The payment method is already registered. How I can ask the user to go through 3D Secure process one more time to get a new nonce in UI? I can't find any documentation or example for this.

Do you have experience with this? Any ideas? Thank you!!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]